Injective immersion
If $M$ and $N$ are real manifolds of the same dimension, and $f: M \rightarrow N$ is an injective immersion, then by the inverse function theorem it is a local diffeomorphism. Then why isn't it always an embedding? Is there a counterexample? In the typical examples I have seen dim(M)<dim(N).

This example is an injective immersion $f: (a,b) \rightarrow R^2$ dim(M)=1 and dim(N)=2. I assumed that $M$ and $N$ have the same dimension.

@RezaBidar I'm not sure why you think it isn't always an embedding. It is; this is proven in e.g. Proposition 4.22.d) in Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"

@Ben Steffan I See. I thought it should be. I found Proposition 4.22.d) in Lee's Thank you so much!

The typical example, for instance is in Lee’s Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. An explicit function is $\beta:(-\pi,\pi)\to \Bbb{R}^2$ given by $\beta(t)=(\sin 2t, \sin t)$. This is an injective immersion which is not embedding (the image is a figure eight, which is a compact subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$, so if $\beta$ were an embedding, the domain $(-\pi,\pi)=\beta^{-1}(\text{image}(\beta))$ would have to be compact, as the continuous image of a compact set, but it is not).
A counterexample to injective immersions not being embeddings necessarily requires $\dim M<\dim N$. If $\dim M=\dim N$ and $f:M\to N$ is an injective immersion, then it an injective local diffeomorphism, so the image $f(M)$ is open in $N$, and $f:M\to f(M)$ is a diffeomorphism. In particular, the inverse map $f(M)\to M$ is continuous, hence $f:M\to N$ is an embedding.

Thanks very much for a detailed explanation.
